# How to switch branch with selected changes and replace a commit in sourcetree?

Tags: git, github, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm struggling when get things done with git, especially with sourceTree

**Question1**

For example, I have 3 branches,

```
--dev

----branch1
----branch2
```

Then i changes or edit some files in branch1 , like `editBranch1.js, editBranch2js, editEnvironment.js, .npmrc` , then i change the branch, but I don't want to bring changes to branch2, but there are some change must show at both branch like `editEnvironment.js, .npmrc`

So how can I switch branch with only these selected changes in sourceTree?

**Question 2**

Then I commit and push these changes on branch1 but I accidentally commit some change don't related to my brand, then my lead so mad, told me to undo this, until now I have only choice, delete that branch and changes I made

That so annoying when I spend hours to code, now throw them away because some changes, so my question is:

If I **`committed and pushed`**, how can I undo that and keep all changes I made, or how can I **`undo push`** and still save changes on my local branch, then I can uncheck unwanted changes and push again?

Please help, thank you a lot

Comment: Please help :((

Comment: I think you have completely misunderstood what branches are for on git, although if you are working in a team (and sounds like you are) the most important thing is to know the team/company SCM plan and to follow that. Branches are effectively separate versions of the repo. Typically the above pattern is used for isolated development - so branch1 and branch2 will be shortlived versions used for specific feature branches, integrated back to dev and then deleted. You should not mix them up. You can back out changes or start again - suggest you get some training...